# how can i call a method in wcf (hosted as windows service) from c# client?

Tags: c#, wcf, web-services

i have created a wcf service and host it to iis. and finally i access the service methods from the client by adding that service  as  a reference.  this add service reference is already available in .net.

i have hosted a wcf service as windows service. now i have to access that service methods from the client. i dont know how to proceed in this point. please help me to resolve this.

is i need to add the service reference  in a client application  if the wcf service is hosted as windows service?

Comment: Whether your WCF service is hosted in IIS or inside a Windows service doesn't make **any difference** to the way you connect to it - just use `Add Service Reference` and type in the URL where the service endpoint is exposed at.

Comment: Two other options are to use svcutil to generate a proxy for your client, or to use `ChannelFactory<T>` in your code, as long as your code has the interface for the contract (the `T` part of `ChannelFactory<T>` - like `ChannelFactory<IService1>`.  Just make sure the Windows Service is running when you try to add the service reference or run svcutil.

Comment: @marc_s: Thanks your suggestion works fine. now i got answer. Thanks.